# How to update the page and query parameters in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a page with a search field. If accessed with a query parameter (e.g. `?word=cat`) the page should load with results present and the search field filled. If a search is done the results and the query parameters (browser history) should update.

The only way I found to update query parameters is `goto`, so my attempt is:

```html
<script context="module">
  export async function load({ page, fetch }) {
    const response = await fetch(`/data.json?${page.query.toString()}`)
    if (response.ok) {
      return {
        props: {
          word: page.query.get('word'),
          body: await response.json()
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<script>
  import { goto } from '$app/navigation'
  import { page } from '$app/stores'

  export let word
  export let body

  function search() {
    $page.query.set('word', word)
    goto(`?${$page.query.toString()}`)
  }
</script>

<main>
  <form on:submit|preventDefault={search}>
    <input bind:value={word}>
  </form>
  <!-- ... -->
</main>
```

This works but sometimes gets stuck just updating the query parameters and nothing else. For some reason `load` isn't being called in those cases. I can get it to work reliably by adding `await invalidate` for the URL before the `goto`, but now `load` is always called twice and the search field flips back to the old value shortly.

I just started with Svelte/SvelteKit, so my approach is probably just wrong. Thanks for any help.

Comment: try removing the `$page.query.set` line and simple have `goto` that should be enough

Comment: Thanks, I replaced it with a separate `URLSearchParams` and it works.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had similar issue triggering `load` function and I solved it by creating new instance of the `URLSearchParams` and navigating to these new params.

```js
let query = new URLSearchParams($page.url.searchParams.toString());
    
query.set('word', word);
        
goto(`?${query.toString()}`);
```

Comment: You don't actually have a create a new URLSearchParams object passing the page.query. the `$page.url.searchParams;` already returns a urlSearchParams object so you can just assign that to a variable: 

```const urlSearchParams = $page.url.searchParams; ```

Comment: @Nicholas Mordecai I respectfully disagree. See Anatole Lucet's comment.

Answer (score 18):

`$page.query` is no longer available since it was replaced by `$page.url` (in [@sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.208](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/3124)).

Now, it is done like this:

```js
$page.url.searchParams.set('word',word); 
goto(`?${$page.url.searchParams.toString()}`);
```

`$page` and `goto()` you can get from:

```js
import { goto } from "$app/navigation";
import { page } from "$app/stores";
```

Comment: Actually, this will mutate `page`'s internal `URLSearchParams` which might cause some issues when working with reactive statements.

A better way would be to create and mutate a new `URLSearchParams` from `$page.url.searchParams`, and then use it in the `goto` (`goto(newSearchParams)`).

Answer (score 4):

You can pass in a URL type in goto function.

```js
const newUrl = new URL($page.url);
newUrl?.searchParams?.set('hello', 'world');
goto(newUrl);
```

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-stores-page
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto

Answer (score 1):

An even shorter approach:

```js
$page.query.set('word',word); 
goto(`?${$page.query.toString()}`);
```

Comment: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2785

Answer (score 0):

To prevent an extra navigation and reload:

```
$page.query.set('word',word); 
history.replaceState(history.state, '', $page.url);
```