# SvelteKit: Unrecoverable HMR error in <+page>: next update will trigger a full reload

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, webpack-hmr

I am building a small website and in a page there are a form and a table that displays some query output based on the user input. On first loading, I have no problems because I inserted some code in the onMount function that set up the page. When the used submits the form a second time, the webpage remains the same, but onMount is not triggered. For this reason, I used the $: notation so that each time a new form is submitted, I can set up the page accordingly. The issue is that when I insert the update_buttons() function in the $: part, I get the error displayed in the thread title. Why do I get this error?

```
<script>
import {onMount} from 'svelte';
import Table from './Table.svelte';
import Criteria from './Criteria.svelte';
import {init_page, update_buttons} from './update-shipments.js';

export let data;

$: {
    document.page=0;
    document.shipments_num=data.shipments_num;
    document.form_input = data.form_input;
    update_buttons();
}

onMount(() => {
    init_page();
    update_buttons();
});
</script>
```

update_buttons function

```
export function update_buttons() {
if (document.page==0) {
    document.getElementById("prev-button").disabled=true;
} else {
    document.getElementById("prev-button").disabled=false;
}

if (document.page*30+30>=document.shipments_num) {
    document.getElementById("next-button").disabled=true;
} else {
    document.getElementById("next-button").disabled=false;
}
}
```

Alternatively, is there any way to run some code each time a new form is submitted, even when the page remains the same and the only thing changing are the URL parameters?

---

As suggested by @Stephane Vanraes i refactored the whole page to to take advantage of the svelte functionalities and now everything works. To be more specific now the buttons are set up like this

```
<button id="prev-button" class="btn {data.page == 0 ? "disabled" : null}" on:click={() => update_shipments("prev")}>back</button>
<button id="next-button" class="btn {data.page*30+30 >= data.shipments_num ? "disabled" : null}" on:click={() => update_shipments("next")}>forw</button>
```

Meanwhile the query output, like shipments_num is now solely managed as an attributed of the data variable.

Comment: To execute an action on form submit, create a callback function for the form's `on:submit` event. Do not use reactivity here. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69606222/3422060).

Comment: The code you post is very "un-Svelte" as well, why are you placing props on the document and using `getElementbyId` ? all of that should just be state, maybe a store even.

Comment: Thanks to you both, i refactored the page following Stephane's advice and now everything works. Sorry if the original question was a bit strange but until very recently i have been using only express so I'm not very familiar with the Svelte workflow.